# How to list all securityContext of kubernetes pod and its container

Tags: kubernetes

Is there anyway to list all securityContext including default and defined:

1. Pod Level
2. Container Level

Using `kubectl get pod -o yaml` only show the defined in `spec.securityContext` and `spec.containers[*].securityContext` of manifest without the default one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you are, source can be found [in this medium article](https://medium.com/@pjbgf/kubectl-list-security-context-settings-for-all-pods-containers-within-a-cluster-93349681ef5d):

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o go-template \
    --template='{{range .items}}{{"pod: "}}{{.metadata.name}}
{{if .spec.securityContext}}
  PodSecurityContext:
    {{"runAsGroup: "}}{{.spec.securityContext.runAsGroup}}                               
    {{"runAsNonRoot: "}}{{.spec.securityContext.runAsNonRoot}}                           
    {{"runAsUser: "}}{{.spec.securityContext.runAsUser}}                                 {{if .spec.securityContext.seLinuxOptions}}
    {{"seLinuxOptions: "}}{{.spec.securityContext.seLinuxOptions}}                       {{end}}
{{else}}PodSecurity Context is not set
{{end}}{{range .spec.containers}}
{{"container name: "}}{{.name}}
{{"image: "}}{{.image}}{{if .securityContext}}                                      
    {{"allowPrivilegeEscalation: "}}{{.securityContext.allowPrivilegeEscalation}}   {{if .securityContext.capabilities}}
    {{"capabilities: "}}{{.securityContext.capabilities}}                           {{end}}
    {{"privileged: "}}{{.securityContext.privileged}}                               {{if .securityContext.procMount}}
    {{"procMount: "}}{{.securityContext.procMount}}                                 {{end}}
    {{"readOnlyRootFilesystem: "}}{{.securityContext.readOnlyRootFilesystem}}       
    {{"runAsGroup: "}}{{.securityContext.runAsGroup}}                               
    {{"runAsNonRoot: "}}{{.securityContext.runAsNonRoot}}                           
    {{"runAsUser: "}}{{.securityContext.runAsUser}}                                 {{if .securityContext.seLinuxOptions}}
    {{"seLinuxOptions: "}}{{.securityContext.seLinuxOptions}}                       {{end}}{{if .securityContext.windowsOptions}}
    {{"windowsOptions: "}}{{.securityContext.windowsOptions}}                       {{end}}
{{else}}
    SecurityContext is not set
{{end}}
{{end}}{{end}}'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Note that links to third-party sites is not ideal, they could break over time, ... It's usually better to just paste some code snippets as part of your answer.